# R Shiny - Rendering multiple image or plot in 1 page (multiple as in 1000+)

Tags: r, image, plot, shiny

I need to render multiple image or plot (whichever faster works for me) in Shiny web app. By multiple I mean about 1000+ image. I am trying to create a kind of dashboard of heat-o-meter gauges to show the status of a server whether it is in healthy condition or not. I am aware of how to render multiple image and plot in Shiny but to scale up to 1000+ and render them in a short amount of time is a challenge. Is there any way to do it in faster?

I have tried several methods such as:

1. creating multiple plots, putting them into list, and display them
       using grid.arrange from gridExtra package. Problem here is
       grid.arrange() takes a lot of time to render for 1000+ images.
2. creating multiple plot in 1 image, save them to png, and display the png file. Also same problem like grid.arrange() method. It takes a lot of time.
3. Render and save the plot for every servers beforehand in multiple image and display the image when any of the server is
   called. Would like to know how esp for 1000+ image? and to render that many images I am afraid there
       will be performance issue also.
4. Any other method? I am wondering if Shiny is able to pre-render all the plots once then let the users see it when they go into the Shiny web-app website. But that does not seem how Shiny works. The web-app process is re-started whenever user access the website.

Comment: Don't forget that a plot is for a human to view. Are you sure someone wants to view 1000+ plots?

Comment: I am aware of the functionality issue. It does sound 'ridiculous'. But it is needed nevertheless. It is not exactly a plot, but more like a meter/gauge to show status of a server. I created another Shiny page that able to search and display the heatmeter for necessary server but apparently that's not good enough for management.

Comment: Is it considerably faster to generate the 1000+ plots as individual images stored in separate PNG files than to use `grid.arrange` to make a tiled big image? If yes, you might try whether `EBImage::tile` wouldn't be faster than `grid.arrange` to create the final composite image from individual PNG files.

Comment: @aoles Let me try this method and see the performance.

Comment: @addicted Great! I'm really interested to learn about the actual bottleneck. It can be that the performance of the plotting function itself is an issue here. Then you probably would need to look for alternatives or implement a customized function optimized for your type of input. Looking forward to hearing from you.